# Improving poor edge detection results in pyopencv (cv2.Canny)

Tags: python, opencv, optimization, edge-detection

I'm trying to use edge detection on some of my photos and im not getting good results as in the example on the open [cv website](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html)

I've created a script which iteratively generates plots with different detection limits and played around with lots of different parameters but can't seem to get decent results.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('Topaz.jpg',0)
#edges = cv2.Canny(img,500,600)

lower = np.linspace(start=0, stop=255, num=10)
upper = np.linspace(start=0, stop=255, num=10)

save_as = "Plot.png"


def vary_thresh(img, upper, lower, save_as):
    blur = cv2.blur(img,(3,3))
    #blur = img
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    sp = 0
    plot_count = 0
    for i in lower:
        for b in upper:
            edges = cv2.Canny(blur,i,b, L2gradient = False)
            if abs(i - b) < 150:
                print ("Invalid range skipping")
                continue
            sp += 1
            print ("Plot #: " + str(sp))
            plt.subplot(15,3,sp),plt.imshow(edges,cmap = 'gray')
            plt.title("L = " + str(round(i)) + "U" + str(round(b)))
    print(sp)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(save_as)


vary_thresh(img, upper, lower, save_as)
```

~~ I'm not sure how to post the example image I'm using (first time on here) but I'm happy to if there is away. can also give screenshots of the outputs im getting. ~~

Here is the image 
https://i.imgur.com/BKduCLg.jpg

And here is an example of the output
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnI5R.jpg

Comment: Post your input image to some free hosting service and put the URL here so we can see what image you are trying to process. JPG is a lossy compressed format and loses information, which may be causing your issue. Or perhaps your image content is poor for doing edge detection. It is hard to know what might be the issue without seeing your image.

Comment: Added an edit with the image and an example of the outputs i'm getting. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I've now tried it with a .tif file with no compression and still getting the same results as with a .jpg

Comment: You do not have strong and continuous color transitions in the image for canny to detect as edges. The background is textured and that is not good for detecting edges between your foreground "dog" and background "grass". Perhaps a bilateral filter might help.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for. After a quick fiddle, it seems to improve the results. I'll try and improve further and combine with some other things I've been trying ill post an answer here to help others.